# Canvas total width (visible width + hidden scrollable part)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

It's probably a no brainer, but I've spent the last 40 minutes or so looking for it to no avial.

I have a Canvas control with a fixed width and a horizontal scrollbar.
I'm trying to find the actual width of the control.
The .width (fixed width) + the part being revealed by the scrollbar.
I tried explicitWidth, width + maxHorizontalScrollPosition, and some other combos but non of them hit the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it seem `width + maxHorizontalScrollPosition` is indeed enough.
The problem was with the order of events in my application (the scrollbar didn't have enough time to update it's display). I ended up adding a custom event to the class representing the content of the Canvas.