# Integrate overflowed links into a dynamic dropdown menu at the end of the list of menu

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, overflow, flex4.5, fluid-layout

How should I create a horizontal list of links such that overflowed links are still available through a dynamic dropdown menu at the end of the list?

I want to be able to create an list of links (or buttons) such that when there is enough horizontal space all links are shown. When there is not enough horizontal space the overflowed links will appear in a drop down menu at the end of the link list. I am using Flex SDK 4.5.1.

This desired behavior is shown below.

[image]

After experimenting with creating a multi-part custom component, using a custom layout and fairly extensive but not successful research on the internet I have not  come any closer to a workable solution.

How should I create a horizontal list of links such that overflowed links are available through a dropdown list at the end of the main list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot research, reading, and many prototypes, I worked through a solution that functions well enough for this specific scenario; albeit, the coupling between components and skins is a bit higher than I would have liked.

I created a custom component based on the spark `BorderContainer`. The component layout is roughly:

```
-- BorderContainer
  -- Scroller
    -- Group
      -- DataGroup
      -- Button
      -- PopUpAnchor
        -- Group
        -- Rect
        -- DataGroup
```

The first `DataGroup` contains the primary list of items. These are the ones that are displayed horizontally. By overriding `updateDisplayList` in the custom component I can measure each item in the `DataGroup` and determine whether or not it will fit in the available area. Those that do not fit are made invisible (not removed) and added to a do not show list.

Those items in the do not show list are added to the second `DataGroup`. This is the drop down list. Wrapping up this `DataGroup` in a `PopUpAnchor` allows me to add drop down menu like behavior. The `Button` is used to pop up and close the second `DataGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

- [calculate the visible width plus the scrollable width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670280/canvas-total-width-visible-width-hidden-scrollable-part)
- [divide the scrollable width by the width of each link plus the separator to decide how many items to move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715341/changin-the-default-width-and-height-of-the-dropdownlist)
- [pop the hidden items from the list dataProvider to remove the scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428597/how-to-get-flex-3-combobox-width-to-adjust-based-on-bound-dataprovider-contents)
- [and push them to the popupMenu dataProvider](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/28/setting-the-width-on-a-flex-popupbutton-controls-pop-up-menu/)